# Why do I need a tty to run sudo if I can sudo without a password?

Tags: ssh, sudo, tty

I have configured `sudo` to run without a password, but when I try to `ssh 'sudo Foo'`, I still get the error message `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`.

Why does this happen and how can I work around it?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

That's probably because your `/etc/sudoers` file (or any file it includes) has:

```
Defaults requiretty
```

...which makes `sudo` require a TTY. Red Hat systems (RHEL, Fedora...) have been known to require a TTY in default `sudoers` file. That provides no real security benefit and can be safely removed.

[Red Hat have acknowledged the problem](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020147) and it will be removed in future releases.

If changing the configuration of the server is not an option, as a work-around for that mis-configuration, you could use the `-t` or `-tt` options to `ssh` which spawns a pseudo-terminal on the remote side, but beware that it has a number of side effects.

`-tt` is meant for interactive use. It puts the local terminal in `raw` mode so that you interact with the remote terminal. That means that if `ssh` I/O is not from/to a terminal, that will have side effects. For instance, all the input will be echoed back, special terminal characters (`^?`, `^C`, `^U`) will cause special processing; on output, `LF`s will be converted to `CRLF`s... (see [this answer to *Why is this binary file being changed?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151963/22565) for more details.

To minimise the impact, you could invoke it as:

```
ssh -tt host 'stty raw -echo; sudo ...' < <(cat)
```

The `< <(cat)` will avoid the setting of the local terminal (if any) in `raw` mode. And we're using `stty raw -echo` to set the line discipline of the remote terminal as pass through (effectively so it behaves like the pipe that would be used instead of a pseudo-terminal without `-tt`, though that only applies after that command is run, so you need to delay sending something for input until that happens).

Note that since the output of the remote command will go to a terminal, that will still affect its buffering (which will be line-based for many applications) and bandwidth efficiency since `TCP_NODELAY` is on. Also with `-tt`, `ssh` sets the IPQoS to `lowdelay` as opposed to `throughput`. You could work around both with:

```
ssh -o IPQoS=throughput -tt host 'stty raw -echo; sudo cmd | cat' < <(cat)
```

Also, note that it means  the remote command cannot detect end-of-file  on its stdin and the stdout and stderr of the remote command are merged into a single stream.

So, not so good a work around after all.

If you've a got a way to spawn a pseudo-terminal on the remote host (like with `expect`, `zsh`, `socat`, `perl`'s `IO::Pty`...), then it would be better to use that to create the pseudo-terminal to attach `sudo` to (but not for I/O), and use `ssh` without `-t`.

For example, with `expect`:

```
ssh host 'expect -c "spawn -noecho sh -c {
     exec sudo cmd >&4 2>&5 <&6 4>&- 5>&- 6<&-}
 exit [lindex [wait] 3]" 4>&1 5>&2 6<&0'
```

Or with `script` (here assuming the implementation from `util-linux`):

```
ssh host 'SHELL=/bin/sh script -qec "
              sudo cmd <&3 >&4 2>&5 3<&- 4>&- 5>&-
            " /dev/null 3<&0 4>&1 5>&2'
```

(assuming (for both) that the login shell of the remote user is Bourne-like).

Comment: big thank you for this : I used the last (script -qec ....) trick today. I added some commands before and after :  `ssh host 'cmds before ; SHELL=/bin/sh script -qec "sudo cmdsudoed here with args <&3 >&4 2>&5 3<&- 4>&- 5>&-" /dev/null 3<&0 4>&1 5>&2 ; cmds after here' ` # the ones after don't display ... probably due to all those &- ? Are they mandatory? (if I understand the order correctly: they retrieve the current values(=fd) of stdin, stdout and stderr, redirects (copy) sudo's in/out/err to the same destinations, then close them for script? thus it closes the outer stdin/out/err too?)

Comment: moreover I remember reading on this site somewhere that closing fd0 1 or 2 is not recommended: [edit: found it: of course, it was from you :) ) : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/446591/27616 :  as I don't see output from the commands after the closing of 3, 4, 5: does it mean it closed my ssh shell's 0, 1 and 2 ? and therefore... my successive commands could end up writing in the wrong place? :/

Comment: @OlivierDulac, no `n>&-` (or `n<&-` which is the same) closes fd n. Only `exec 0<&- 1<&- 2<&-` (or `exec <&- >&- 2>&-`) would close stdin/stdout/stderr from now on. We close those fds 3, 4, 5 for sudo, in the shell started by script because neither sudo nor cmd need them and they've served their purpose (restore the original remote shell stdin/out/err inside the script session). I don't know why you don't see the output of `cmds after here`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am puzzled as well, and will need further testing to figure why this is happening...

Comment: Stephane, I have noticed I lose stdout after the first error: in your last (script) exemple, instead of `sudo cmd`, I have: `sudo su - someuser -c  \"id ; echo $? ; cd /_not_a_dir_ ; echo $? ; id\" ` (the rest is the same as in your answer) : I only see the output of the  first id and the 0, and then nothing else. I don't see the error from the cd /_not_a_dir_ , nor the subsequent echo $?, nor the last id. if I instead : cd / ; I see all (stdout) outputs

Comment: @OlivierDulac, you may want to use `sudo -Hu someuser sh -c...` here. You'd also need to quote those `$`s. so they're not expanded by the shell run by `screen`.

Answer (score 32):

By default, SUDO is configured to require a TTY.  That is, SUDO is expected to be run from a login shell.  You can defeat this requirement by adding the `-t` switch to your SSH invocation:

```
ssh -t someserver sudo somecommand
```

The `-t` forces allocation of a pseudo-tty.

If you want to perform this globally, modify `/etc/sudoers` to specify `!requiretty`.  This can be done a a per user, per group or all-encompassing level.

Comment: No, that's not the default. It's only the redhat distribution of sudo that had `requiretty` in its default sudoers. [It will be fixed in newer releases](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1020147)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas +1 for enlightening me that it's largely indigenous to Red Hat and its siblings and another ++ if I could for the current bug report!

Answer (score 19):

Use the `-t` flag to `ssh` to force tty allocation.

```
$ ssh luci tty
not a tty
$ ssh luci -t tty
/dev/ttys003
$
```

Comment: Add a second `-t` to force allocation when `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.`

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this problem using Docker and Centos 7. I ended up doing the following:

`yum install -y sudo`

`sed -i -e 's/Defaults    requiretty.*/ #Defaults    requiretty/g' /etc/sudoers`

I found this hack at https://hub.docker.com/r/liubin/fluentd-agent/~/dockerfile

Comment: This answer made the most sense for me, using Docker and CentOS 7 as well.  It was easy to understand as well as copy/paste friendly!

Answer (score 1):

An interesting alternative is to run FreeIPA or IdM to manage your users and sudoer rules centrally. You can then create sudo rules and assign the option

!requiretty

in the rule. The command will then run as expected. You will also have the benefits of managing all the servers and users from a single set of configurations.

Answer (score 1):

One more option that I didn't see in replies in any such questions is `open_init_pty`.  I was unable to change sudo configuration as well as to provide -t option in any quantity (in fact you can't do anything if ssh is called by Java program such as bamboo or anything like that).  Suddenly, `man -k pty` solved my problem.

So my solution was to change `sh very_useful_script.sh` to `/usr/sbin/open_init_pty /bin/sh very_useful_script.sh`.  You cant call `sudo` directly, for example `open_init_pty sudo -u wildfly id`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while Googling and I encountered this error for a completely different reason.

My fix was to stop calling downstream shell scripts as `sudo` from my parent shell script, when the parent shell script was already called with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, the solution was two lines

```
myscript=$(cat ssh_test.sh)
ssh -t user@host "$myscript"
```

Explanation:

- Place the commands you want to run (including sudo commands) into a script e.g. "ssh_test.sh".
- Read the whole script into a variable called "myscript".
- Invoke ssh with just one -t and supply the variable instead of a command.

Prior to this, I ran into problems using combinations of reading from stdin and using heredocs