# forcing sudo on remote rsync server

Tags: permissions, sudo, rsync

I'm setting up `rsync` to transfer files from ServerA to ServerB, and need to preserve timestamps and permissions.   They key here is the files are owned by a different account than the one performing the file transfer.

`rsync` transfers files using the example below:

```
rsync -a /colorschemes/ acoder@bu.my.box.net:/colorschemes/ --delete
```

The `-a` flag yields the following types of errors:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/colorschemes/946/ex": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: failed to set permissions on "/colorschemes/946/ex/blue.pdf": Operation not permitted (1)
```

On the remote system, the acoder account has a similar error when attempting to manually set permissions on a file:

```
[acoder@bu ~]$ chown apache:codingteam /colorschemes/946
chown: changing ownership of ‘/colorschemes/946’: Operation not permitted
```

This works OK, though:

```
[acoder@bu ~]$ sudo chown apache:codingteam /colorschemes/946
```

Is there a way to make the remote rsync use sudo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For using `sudo` with `rsync` in remote machine you can call it with `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` but be aware of the `require TTY`, you skip it by removing `Defaults requiretty` from `sudoers` file.

If you want to change the permission for anything you don't own, you have to use `sudo` if you were not `root`

or there is a different way like setting a `setuid` on `chmod`, `chown` then any one can run the `chmod`, `chown` as a `root`, but that will be **horrible**.

Comment: @acoder i edited my question so u add a way to do that

Comment: @acoder you can use `sudo` with `--rsync-path="sudo rsync"` but make sure you make the user `acoder` require no password for using `rsync` with `sudo`

Comment: Ok, so `--rsync-path` is used to set the path of rsync on the remote computer.   Will try that and follow up.

Comment: "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Comment: Ok so this answer says it's safe to remove the `Defaults requiretty` line from the sudoers file.   Gave that a go, and it worked.   

http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122624/20107

Comment: Done.  I've removed a couple of my extraneous comments to help clean up this question & answer. :)